# Java Swing Displaying Large Amounts of Data from ArrayLists

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, large-data

I cannot provide code because this is an abstract problem that I am currently facing.

I am working on a program which allows a user to track players from games. The program essentially stores a players profile information in an ArrayList. One feature of my program that I would like is to let the user be able to browse through the entire ArrayList of players.

Let's say that I have an ArrayList of `Player` objects and the size is very large, say `1000`. Is it possible in Java to allow the user to scroll through the ArrayList? I thought about creating 10 `JLabels` and each time a user clicked a button it would iterate through the ArrayList to the next 10 `Player` objects. But this does not seem practical.

Are there any Swing features I can utilize for this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using a JTable, in which each table row contains the information for each player. You can extend the class AbstractTableModel to define the fields per player, and which player gets displayed on which table row.

I've written a Java app which uses JTables with more than 2000 rows, and about 15 to 20 columns, and had no performance issues. To limit the displayed rows, you can also use RowFilter, and you can customise the sorting using RowSorter.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will look more into JTables. If anyone has anymore suggestion I am open to them!

Comment: @RowenMcDaniel: re, `"I will look more into JTables. If anyone has anymore suggestion I am open to them!"` --  no, this *is* the correct answer. Accept this answer and start coding. The key is that the JTable with its use of rendering will be much more efficient than your solution that involves creation and display of many components.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you for ensuring this answer :D.